# Scroll on a specific DIV Element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do a simple Python Selenium automation where the script will click a link which opens a dialog box on top of the page (Instagram profile).

The said dialog box will display the list of followers but unfortunately the UL that contains the list will only display the first 12 followers (or LI). It is powered by AJAX to "load more" followers.

Anyway, to simulate loading more followers, i tried this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/ul').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. I was wondering if there is a correct way to do this (scrolling down focused on the active div or any page element)?

Image below is provided to show the html structure of the said page.

[image]

Appreciate your help on this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this**

```
liElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='dialog']//ul//li[text()='required_li_element_visible_text']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", liElement);
```

Comment: i got this error:

    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@role='dialog']//ul//li[text()='required_li_element_visible_text']"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Comment: never mind, fixed the minor issue. Thanks for your help Sir, have a great day!

Answer (score 7):

Can you try something like this?. This will scroll to the div element that you have mentioned.

**Python Code**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_div_element")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

**Java sample:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_div_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: This isnt working for me. I have to way down to the div and no it doesnt go.